# Is there a way in React to save something in state without using any hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a prop which is only populated the first 6 times a component renders, and then is lost. I need to save the value from this prop and make it available in the 7th and 8th renders of the component. So my thought was to do this:

```
function MyComponent ({ myProp, ...props }) {
  const [mySavedValue, setMySavedValue] = useState();

  if (myProp && mySavedValue) {
    setMySavedValue(myProp)
   }

...
```

However, this is putting a useState hook inside a condition, which is bad. It causes an infinite loop.

Error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

How can I save this value into a place that will persist throughout all re-renders? Is there a way to save to state without using useState hooks that will cause this problem?

Comment: `setMySavedValue` is not a hook (`useState` is a hook, but the setter that it returns is not) and there is nothing wrong with putting it in an if statement

Comment: TBH saving props in component state is bad and an anti-pattern in react. Why is the prop only defined for 6 render cycles? It is probably more valuable to figure that out than to write poor quality code.

Comment: @DrewReese it is because this is a split route, so for the first 6 renders it's in the first route, then it moves on to the second route. The prop I need access to happens to be HTTP Referrer so that can only be available in the first route because the referrer changes (and the second route doesn't have access to the referrer).

Answer (score 1):

If the *same component* gets re-rendered (that is, it doesn't get un-mounted, then re-mounted), then putting the prop into state immediately, and then referencing the stateful variable, should do what you're looking for:

```
function MyComponent ({ myProp: myPropParam, ...props }) {
  const [myProp] = useState(myPropParam);
  // reference myProp here
```

That said, it's pretty odd for a prop to be present initially and then to be lost. A better solution would be to change the parent component's code so that the props that get passed down are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which is your use case but if you don't want to keep in an infinite loop, what you have to do is the `useEffect` hook.

What's causing that infinite loop is that every time the functional component re-renders, it executes all the code inside it, hence that if statement gets executed when appropriate => sets state => re-renders => so on...

So, maybe it makes sense to you this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (myProp && mySavedValue) {
    setMySavedValue(myProp)
   }
}, [myProp]);
```

Since I am assuming that the prop could change in some of the first 6 renders.